# C++: Error with user defined type array

Tags: c++, arrays, user-defined-types

My errors seem to be derivative of this error:

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'itemArray'
```

There is no missing semicolon but I also get this error on the same line:

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

I don't understand why either of these errors occur.

**Order.h**

```
#ifndef ORDER_H
#define ORDER_H

const int MAX_ITEMS = 20;

class Order{

private:
    int items;
    Item itemArray[MAX_ITEMS]; //error seems to occur here
    int orderNum;
    int guestNum;
    double total;
    bool isOpen = true;

public:
    Order();
    ~Order();

    void AddItem();
    void DeleteItem();
    void ChangeItem();
    void CloseOrder();
    void DisplayOrderDetails();
    void SetGuestNum();
};

#endif ORDER_H
```

**Order.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Order.h"
#include "Item.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


...
```

**Item.h**

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Item
{
private:
    double price = 0;
    string name = "";
    bool active = false;
    int itemNum = 0;

public:
    Item();
    ~Item();
    void CreateItem();
    void ChangeItemName();
    void ChangeItemPrice();
    void RemoveItem();

    bool GetActive();
    int GetItemNum();
    string GetName();
    double GetPrice();
};

#endif ITEM_H
```

**Item.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Item.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


Item::Item()
{
    static int currentNum = 0;
    itemNum = ++currentNum;
}
...
```

What is the problem and how do I fix it?
Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you include `Item.h` in `Order.h`? Here is not present.

Comment: Does `Order.h` include `Item.h`?

Comment: If you don't `#include "Item.h"` in Order.h, how would the compiler know what an `Item` is to generate code for handling it? You're going to have a similar problem in Item.cpp also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `Item` is unknown before:

```
Item itemArray[MAX_ITEMS]; //error seems to occur here
```

it should work if you add: `#include "Item.h"` before `Order` class definition, or switch:

```
#include "Order.h"
#include "Item.h"
```

to:

```
#include "Item.h"
#include "Order.h"
```

Comment: Indeed, I needed the `#include "Item.h"` before the `Order` class definition! It seems strange that Visual Studio would continue to highlight `Item` as a known class though.